# Django form cleaned data "too many values to unpack" error

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a very simple login form :

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100,required = True)
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(),max_length=100,required = True)
```

I am using it following way in the views :

```
def login(request):
 msg = []
 form = LoginForm()
 if request.method == 'POST':
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       username = form.cleaned_data['username']
       password = form.cleaned_data['password']    
       user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
```

I get the error too many values to unpack. What am I doing wrong ? If you need any more information please comment.

Comment: Which line gives the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there might be a problem in the password.
reset the password and try again

```
python manage.py shell
>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>> u = User.objects.get(username="myuser")
>> u.set_password("mypassword")
>> u.save()
```

or delete the db, and made syncdb again(`python manage.py syncdb`), creating new superuser.